# How would you compare two big ( cca 2 mil rows x 60 cols) dataframes / data tables?

Tags: r, dataframe, db2, compare

I have seen a few methods that, how can i compare ( compare_df, dplyr, etc.) and they are effective enough. However when i would like to compare big or huge dataframes i get memory exhausted error, so i would like to ask some method how can i do it better.

I have datas in DB2 databases/data tables, i could accept server side solutions too if there is any.
The task is basicly that i should find all the differences between the two data table. I could use primary key as a join.

Also i taught that it could be a solution if i'd concatenate rows into one string and i compare that on primary key join (and in this case i could have only 2 columns) but i should get where is the difference between the two rows, so it would be an extrastep.

Any out-of-box ideas are welcomed.

Comment: How do you like to get the difference for some row exactly? In 60 columns of the result set or in one column? Somehow else?

Comment: I'd prefer to get back a dataframe where the differences marked somehow. However could go with just  indexes as well( for example: if it give back that there is a difference between the two dataframe at "id: 6253 at col 14")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following **as is** using handy [DISTINCT predicate](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r_predicate_distinct.html) (starting from Db2 11.1). Equivalent expressions may be used for earlier versions, but they are a little bit longer.

```
WITH 
  A (ID, C1, C2) AS 
(
VALUES
  (1, '=', '=')
, (2, '=', '=')
, (4, 'A', '=')
, (5, '=', NULL)
, (6, 'A', 'A')
)
, B (ID, C1, C2) AS 
(
VALUES
  (1, '=', '=')
, (3, '=', '=')
, (4, 'B', '=')
, (5, '=', NULL)
, (6, 'B', 'B')
)
SELECT 
  COALESCE(A.ID, B.ID) AS ID
,  CASE 
    WHEN A.ID IS NULL THEN '-A' 
    WHEN B.ID IS NULL THEN '-B'
    ELSE ''
   END
|| CASE WHEN A.ID = B.ID AND A.C1 IS DISTINCT FROM B.C1 THEN ', C1' ELSE '' END  
|| CASE WHEN A.ID = B.ID AND A.C2 IS DISTINCT FROM B.C2 THEN ', C2' ELSE '' END
--...
--|| CASE WHEN A.ID = B.ID AND A.C60 IS DISTINCT FROM B.C60 THEN ', C60' ELSE '' END
  AS FLAG
FROM A
FULL JOIN B ON B.ID = A.ID
WHERE 
   A.ID IS DISTINCT FROM A.ID
OR A.C1 IS DISTINCT FROM B.C1
OR A.C2 IS DISTINCT FROM B.C2
--...
--OR A.C60 IS DISTINCT FROM B.C60;
```

The result is:

```
|ID         |FLAG      |
|-----------|----------|
|4          |, C1      |
|6          |, C1, C2  |
|3          |-A        |
|2          |-B        |
```

We use `FULL OUTER JOIN` between 2 tables with the following OR conditions:

- The KEY (`ID`) is NULL for one of these tables only (there is no match in the counterpart table by this KEY)
- There is a difference in one of the corresponding column values

The `FLAG` column contains the type of difference:

- `-TABNAME` - the absence of the KEY in the table `TABNAME`
- `, Cx` - there is a difference in the column `Cx` - for each such a column

If you have a large number of columns in both tables, you may generate the corresponding expressions for this `SELECT` statement using a number of Db2 system views.
For example, if we want to generate such expressions for the `SYSIBM.SYSTABLES` table, 
using one of its unique indexes (you must choose such an index, preferably the one supporting primary key), then run this as is to check:

```
SELECT 
  '|| CASE WHEN ' || I.KEY_EXPR || ' AND A.' || C.COLNAME || ' IS DISTINCT FROM B.' || C.COLNAME || ' THEN '', ' || COLNAME || ''' ELSE '''' END' AS SELECT_LIST_EXPR
, 'OR A.' || C.COLNAME || ' IS DISTINCT FROM B.' || C.COLNAME AS WHERE_EXPR
FROM 
  SYSCAT.COLUMNS C
, TABLE 
(
SELECT LISTAGG('A.' || U.COLNAME || ' = B.' || U.COLNAME, ' AND ') AS KEY_EXPR 
FROM SYSCAT.INDEXES I
JOIN SYSCAT.INDEXCOLUSE U ON U.INDSCHEMA = I.INDSCHEMA AND U.INDNAME = I.INDNAME
WHERE 
    I.TABSCHEMA=C.TABSCHEMA AND I.TABNAME=C.TABNAME
AND I.INDSCHEMA='SYSIBM' AND I.INDNAME='INDTABLES01'
AND I.UNIQUERULE IN ('P', 'U')
) I 
WHERE C.TABSCHEMA='SYSIBM' AND C.TABNAME='SYSTABLES'
--FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way (of many) is

```
(SELECT 'A', * FROM A EXCEPT ALL SELECT 'A', * FROM B)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 'B', * FROM B EXCEPT ALL SELECT 'B', * FROM A)
```

Rows returned that have 'A' in the first column are in TABLEA but not in TABLEB.

Rows returned that have 'B' in the first column are in TABLEB but not in TABLEA.